# How to solve/obtain this Differential Eq?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do you solve/obtain the Differential Eq. of $\cot(p)(q′+1)+2q=0$, $q(\pi/4)=9$?
I tried answering since I think this is Linear but i cant seem to get the solution.

Comment: Took liberty of typesetting for you. To confirm $q$ is a function of $p$? If this is the case, then rewrite as $q' + 2\tan(p)q = -1$, which is first-order, linear and non-homogeneous.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are trying to solve $\cot(p)(q'(p)+1) + 2q(p) = 0$.

Rewrite as $q' + 2\tan(p)q = -1$.

Now find integrating factor $\mu(p) = e^{\int^{p} 2\tan(p)\, dp} = \sec^{2}(p)$ and solve for

$q(p) = \mu(p)^{-1} \int^{p} -\mu(p)\, dp = \cos^{2}(p)(C-\tan(p)) = -\sin(p)\cos(p)+C\cos^{2}(p)$.

Check the initial value to find $C$.

Comment: Is this correct if I do/write it this way?
q' + (2/cot(p))q = -1 & y = -(tan(p)/sec^2(p)) + (19/sec^2(p))
μ(p) = sec^2(p)
(μ(p) * q)' = μ(p) * q(x)    :  (sec^2(p)q)' = -sec^2(p)
(sec^2(p)q)' = -sec^2(p): q = -(tan(p)/sec^2(p)) + (C1/sec^2(p))
*Apply y = -(tan(p)/sec^2(p)) + (19/sec^2(p))
*Then the final answer is
y = -(tan(p)/sec^2(p)) + (19/sec^2(p))

Comment: Yes, your constant should be $C=19$. I'd simplify $\tan(p)/\sec^{2}(p) = \sin(p)\cos(p)$, however.